# Setting the pixel size of super+left/right (split screen)

Tags: gnome, display, shortcuts

Hello I am thinking about getting a 32:9 monitor. But before that I would like to know whether it is possible to set the size of the splitted screen.

By pressing super+left ubuntu18 forces the window to the left and make it half the monitor size.

For my setup I would like to have:

1. super+left: window binds to the left side sets window size to 2/7 of the monitor size
2. super+right: window binds to the right side sets window size to 2/7 of the monitor size
3. super+bottom: window is at the right edge of the left window and size set to 3/7 of the monitor size

Is this achieveable?

EDIT:

I also would be happy If it's generally possible. Better with Ubuntu standard, but I wouldn't mind using some Script. I don't know maybe it's possible through some ubuntu api which allows selecting current window information or smth like that.

Appreciate any help :)

Comment: Certainly (unfortunatelly) not easily possible with Gnome out of the box, but likely scriptable involving tools such as wmctrl (and provided you use the X server - default in Ubuntu 18.04 and 18.10,, and not Wayland)

Comment: The Gnome extension gtile can get you a far way in achieving keyboard shortcut based tiling.

Comment: You sir made me just really really happy. I fought for one hour with gtile till I got that there is a tick for global shortcuts, but now it works like a charm and does exactly what I want. I am so happy. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like vanadium said:

> Certainly (unfortunatelly) not easily possible with Gnome out of the box, but likely scriptable involving tools such as wmctrl (and provided you use the X server - default in Ubuntu 18.04 and 18.10,, and not Wayland) – 
>   The Gnome extension gtile can get you a far way in achieving keyboard shortcut based tiling

I went with gtile it's perfect.